# ReferenceError: color is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am learning the concepts of Functional Programming and came across an exercise that has me pretty stumped. When I go to Invoke `consoleStyler()` in Task 4, it gives me a Reference Error: color is not defined. I followed the step by step instructions on the course to get this current code as well as played around with it myself and I can't seem to satisfy the error. Could someone explain to me why I am getting this error? I genuinely would like to understand what I am doing wrong.

```
// Task 1: Build a function-based console log message generator
function consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt) {
    var message = "%c" + txt;
    var style = `color: ${color};`
    style += `background: ${background};`
    style += `font-size: ${fontSize};`
    console.log(message, style);
}

// Task 2: Build another console log message generator
function celebrateStyler(reason) {
    var fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";
    if (reason == "birthday") {
        console.log(`%cHappy Birthday`, fontStyle);
    } else if (reason == "champions") {
        console.log(`%cCongrats on the title!`, fontStyle);
    } else {
        console.log(message, style);
    }
}

// Task 3: Run both the consoleStyler and the celebrateStyler functions
consoleStyler('#1d5c63', '#ede6db', '4px', 'Congrats!');
celebrateStyler('birthday');

// Task 4: Insert a congratulatory and custom message
function styleAndCelebrate() {
    consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt);
    celebrateStyler(reason);
}
// Call styleAndCelebrate
styleAndCelebrate('ef7c8e', 'fae8e0', '30px', 'You made it!', 'Champions')
```

Comment: Inside the `styleAndCelebrate` function, those variables don't exist. Did you mean to put in your own input?

Comment: if you have function 1 and function 2 inside function 3, then you need to send all parameters to function 3. That way you can use those parameters in function 1 and 2 like you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've moved the `consoleStyler` and `celebrateStyler` functions with your input params inside the `styleAndCelebrate()`. The reason it wasn't working before was because due to scoping, `styleAndCelebrate()` didn't know that value of the params inside its function. Hope this helps.

```js
// Task 1: Build a function-based console log message generator
function consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt) {
  var message = "%c" + txt;
  var style = `color: ${color};`
  style += `background: ${background};`
  style += `font-size: ${fontSize};`
  console.log(message, style);
}

// Task 2: Build another console log message generator
function celebrateStyler(reason, txt) {
  var message = "%c" + txt;
  var fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";
  if (reason == "birthday") {
    console.log(`%cHappy Birthday`, fontStyle);
  } else if (reason == "champions") {
    console.log(`%cCongrats on the title!`, fontStyle);
  } else {
    console.log(message, fontStyle);
  }
}

// Task 3: Run both the consoleStyler and the celebrateStyler functions


// Task 4: Insert a congratulatory and custom message
function styleAndCelebrate() {
  consoleStyler('#1d5c63', '#ede6db', '4px', 'Congrats!');
  celebrateStyler('champions');
}
// Call styleAndCelebrate
styleAndCelebrate();
```

Comment: Now this makes sense! Seeing this and understanding it makes me question the validity of the course material I'm working through. I followed the steps and copy and pasted everything possible just to make sure and it ends up the exact same. Thank you for this breakdown! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your code is trying to use variables that haven't been declared.

The first error is in Task 2, the last else tries to log using the non-existent variables 'message' and 'style'. I assume that was from the exercise and you just forgot to update those like you did with the other conditions.

The other error is in Task 4. When you execute Task 4 you pass it 5 values, but your function declaration for Task 4 doesn't contain any of those input variables.

Task 4 should read as the below to work:

```
// Task 4: Insert a congratulatory and custom message
function styleAndCelebrate(color, background, fontSize, txt, reason) {
    consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt);
    celebrateStyler(reason);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
// Task 1: Build a function-based console log message generator
function consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt) {
  let message = "%c" + txt;
  let style = `color: ${color};`
  style += `background: ${background};`
  style += `font-size: ${fontSize};`
  console.log(message, style);
}

// Task 2: Build another console log message generator
function celebrateStyler(reason) {
   let fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";
  if (reason == 'birthday') {
    console.log(`%cHappy Birthday`, fontStyle)
  } else if (reason == 'champions') {
    console.log(`%cCongrats on the title!`, fontStyle)
  } else {
      consoleStyler();
  }
    
}

// Task 3: Run both the consoleStyler and the celebrateStyler functions
consoleStyler('#1d5c63', '#ede6db', '40px', 'Congrats!');
celebrateStyler('birthday');

// Task 4: Insert a congratulatory and custom message
function styleAndCelebrate(color, background, fontSize, txt, reason) {
    consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt);
    celebrateStyler(reason);
}
// Call styleAndCelebrate
styleAndCelebrate('ef7c8e','fae8e0','30px','You made it!','champions');
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the error **ReferenceError: color is not defined** and finally got the code to work on Coursera. The problem you had was the same as mine. `function styleAndCelebrate()` needs to be `function styleAndCelebrate(color, background, fontSize, txt, reason)` because the arguments need to be passed from `function styleAndCelebrate()` to `consoleStyler()` and `celebrateStyler()` for the code to work.

```
// Task 1: Build a function-based console log message generator
function consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt) {
    let message = "%c" + txt;
    let style = `color: ${color};`
    style += `background: ${background};`
    style += `font-size: ${fontSize};`
    console.log(message, style);
}

// Task 2: Build another console log message generator
function celebrateStyler(reason) {
    let fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";
    if (reason == "birthday") {
        console.log(`%cHappy birthday`, fontStyle);
    } else if (reason == "champions") {
        console.log(`%cCongrats on the title!`, fontStyle);
    } else {
       console.log(message, style);
    }
}

// Task 3: Run both the consoleStyler and the celebrateStyler functions
consoleStyler('#1d5c63', '#ede6db', '40px', 'Congrats!');
celebrateStyler('birthday');

// Task 4: Insert a congratulatory and custom message
function styleAndCelebrate(color, background, fontSize, txt, reason) {
    consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt);  
    celebrateStyler(reason);
}
// Call styleAndCelebrate
styleAndCelebrate('ef7c8e', 'fae8e0', '30px', 'You made it!', 'champions')
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).